# Is this sentence a valid construction?

Tags: phrase-requests, above-below

> I received this in my email.
>   Please be reminded in accordance with the below email.

Is something wrong with this sentence?

Comment: @Mitch: It is - and MW allows 'below' as an adjective (printed etc material only). However, MW sadly does not pronounce on where the word may be positioned relative to the noun it is modifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. *Below* is an adverb, not an adjective, and cannot be used to modify *email*. It has to be 'Please be reminded in accordance with the email below.'

Comment: I see no need for them.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't put one after _email_, but one after _reminded_ is defensible.

Comment: Is there a term for the Chinese whispers analogue where alternate strings are deleted? It looks more fun even than the original.

Comment: Indeed so. Consider how you cannot swap in *below* for any adjective in **“Their eager young eyes stared at the stormy grey sea.”** Because it cannot substitute for an adjective in syntactic tests such as these without yielding an ungrammatical result, this failure provides strong evidence that *below* is **not** an adjective at all.

Comment: I’d call *below* a preposition...

Answer (score 1):

> Please be reminded in accordance with the below email.

Should be:

> Please be reminded, in accordance with the email below.

The comma is separating the clauses.