# To 'throw' a farewell party

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage, email

I would like to write an informal email:

> Sorry for not **throwing** a farewell party

Is *throwing* the right word here?

Comment: **15**. To arrange or give (a party, for example). http://www.thefreedictionary.com/throw However, see **usage note** in Barrie England's answer.

Answer (score 5):

We can certainly speak of throwing a party, but we normally do so when there is actually to be a party. It strikes rather the wrong note when you’re apologising for there not having been one. It would be better to use a more neutral term, and write something like ‘I’m sorry I didn’t give a farewell party, but . . .’ and then give whatever excuse you’ve got.

Comment: Now I gave you an upvote, I like your contributions here, unfortunately your site here has one user that runs around downvoting people (>2000 downvotes) it just makes people feel like not bothering.

Comment: It isn't my site, and I don't myself downvote. Vexatious downvoters should be dealt with by the admins.

Comment: I know you don't downvote, I was meaning your site, as in being a regular user here, I feel ownerships on some of the [se] sites. It was just my last two posts were downvoted and commented on and when I looked at the user, a high rep user, they have over made over 2000 downvotes. I just don't understand people like this, is all, just a passing comment, and they don't make people feel comfortable or welcome to come back

Comment: I thought downvotes were anonymous.

Comment: Oh yes. I see that I have actually downvoted 25 times, but that was early on.

Comment: Barrie most of us downvote at some time or other, but most people are like you and I and make far more upvotes than downvotes :)

Comment: Anyway I like your answers here, you have a lot of knowledge, must be the surname :)

Comment: Kind of you to say so.

Comment: @Skippy - I believe downvotes serve a useful function, in that they fend off mediocrity on the site. Some use it more than others, and perhaps some use it more than we would like, but, looking at your allegation, I not convinced these downvotes are unjustified. Your answer to this question, e.g., doesn't really answer the O.P.'s question (the O.P. didn't ask for an alternative wording). I don't think your comma advice [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125908) is on the mark, either. If you want fewer downvotes, be more careful when you answer.

Comment: @J.R. you have bothered to go through my posts, so you can ping me and offer me criticism on a sunday. Bravo. Really excited to be here. thanks for that helpful bit of info